# Implementing Maven Repository functionality in a normal web application

Tags: java, maven, web-applications

I have some questions about Maven repository and Normal webapplication.

1. Is it possible to create a normal web application which has functionality like a Maven web application in which I can create file similar like pom.xml/settings.xml (as in Maven) and include   tags to get jar file downloaded from servers
2. If it possible then how to implement it in normal java web applications. If not then any similar way to impliment the same.

Referenced links will also be helpful for me
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Sounds like you are creating a repository manager. So why do you like to do this? Have you taken a look at [Archiva](http://archiva.apache.org/index.cgi). What would you like to achieve ?

Comment: Exactly why do you not want to use Maven, but still want to do things similar to Maven? My Eclipse Mavenized web projects are also still "normal" web applications. I can build and deploy them without the help of Maven, as soon as I let Maven download all the dependencies at least once.

Comment: @khmarbaise : Thanks for your kind responce :) . Yes I gone throught Archiva and also build a repository mananger using it. But to use the repository mananger or any central repository i need to create a Maven project that help me download jar using pom.xml/settings.xml. But what I want to do is to use a simple web application instead of a Maven web application and download the libraries from the repository in my project . I am using Netbean IDE.

Comment: @Gimby : Thanks for ur reply. Sorry I forgot to mention that I am using Netbean for doing so. What I mean for "Noraml" web application is  "JAVA Web-Web Application" and the "Maven" is "Maven-Web Application". I want to impliment the functnality in  JAVA Web-Web Application. Thanks

Comment: There is no such thing as a Maven web application, its all Java.

Answer (score 1):

The [eclipse aether](http://eclipse.org/aether/) project provides a library for working with artifacts from repositories.

Take a look at [this sample code](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Aether/Resolving_Dependencies):

```
public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception {
    RepositorySystem repoSystem = newRepositorySystem();
    RepositorySystemSession session = newSession( repoSystem );

    DefaultArtifact artifact = new DefaultArtifact( "org.apache.maven:maven-profile:2.2.1" );
    Dependency dependency = new Dependency( artifact , "compile");

    RemoteRepository central = new RemoteRepository.Builder( "central", "default", "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/" ).build();

    CollectRequest collectRequest = new CollectRequest();
    collectRequest.setRoot( dependency );
    collectRequest.addRepository( central );
    DependencyNode node = repoSystem.collectDependencies( session, collectRequest ).getRoot();

    DependencyRequest dependencyRequest = new DependencyRequest();
    dependencyRequest.setRoot( node );

    repoSystem.resolveDependencies( session, dependencyRequest  );

    PreorderNodeListGenerator nlg = new PreorderNodeListGenerator();
    node.accept( nlg );
    System.out.println( nlg.getClassPath() );
}
```